# Postgresql select multiple records from 2 tables with different number of columns

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have 2 tables in a postgres DB with the following records -:

```
TableA
======
ID       DESC          TEAM       STATUS
254      NSW emp       Sales        A
365      NSW,VIC emp   Sales        L
2345     NSW emp       Post Sales   A
...........
.....



TableB
======
ID      STATE
254     NSW
365     NSW
365     VIC
365     QLD
2345    NT
2345    NSW
...........
```

I want to select the `ID, DESC, STATUS and STATE` from the 2 tables for each unique ID and capture the output in the following format.

```
ID       DESC        STATUS      STATE
254      NSW emp       A          NSW
365      NSW,VIC emp   L          NSW,VIC,QLD
2345     NSW emp       A          NT,NSW
.........
```

Attempted to use SELECT statements together with JOIN/INTERSECT and SELECT ARRAY(.......
this fails with "each INTERSECT querymust have the same number of columns"

Any ideas would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TABLEA.ID,
       DESCR,
       TEAM,
       STATUS,
       array_agg(STATE) 
       FROM TABLEA 
        inner join TABLEB
          ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID 
       GROUP BY TABLEA.ID,DESCR,TEAM,STATUS
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Please don’t just post a code snippet, but explain your solution a bit.

Comment: the inner join -- fetches us the no of columns in both the table that are matched by there id's...

Comment: **The inner join** -- fetches us the no of columns in both the table that are matched by there id's...the** Group by** ----groups us only 1 column of id i.e.., from tablea and the select stmt--- fetches us the state column from tableb...finally the **array_agg**--- it provides u to get all the relations in one line seperated by a comma....all these r matched by there id's only :-) have a nice time...